# Python Google Translate API error

Tags: python, google-translate

I am very to new to python and trying to translate a bunch of keywords using google API. I have an excel file with 3000 keywords which are mix of english, spanish, german etc. Trying to translate everything to English.

However, every time I run my code, I get error at different values. Sometimes, my code give error at 810th keyword while sometime it gives error at 1038 keyword.
And I am not even editing the layout of the file.

**JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Below is my code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas
import math
import time
df = pandas.read_excel(r'Desktop/python_keywords.xlsx')
keywords = df['Keywords']
Translate = []
translator = Translator()

for i in range(0,len(keywords)):
    word = translator.translate(str(keywords[j])).text
    Translate.append(word)
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally this error is due to the character limit of 15K in Googletrans API.

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Consider reducing the number of characters.

Comment: Is it tied to some time constraint or in a one single shot ?

Answer (score 0):

Which line of your code gives you this error? Look at error trace
Let's start with your iterators: it is declared as `i`, but then you use `j`. Then check length of your request. It shouldn't be longer than 5k symbols according to [JSONDecodeError using Google Translate API with Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021371/jsondecodeerror-using-google-translate-api-with-python3).
Anyway, it looks like api responds with empty json and you have to add at least `try .. except` to avoid this error, smth like this:

```
try:  
    word = translator.translate(str(keywords[j])).text  
except JSONDecodeError as err:  
    print(err)  # if you want to see when error happens
else:
    Translate.append(word)
```

Comment: Thanks Nikita. Yeah the iterator is not an issue. I just mistyped it. I think its the character limit.