# Googletrans raising an error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python-3.x, google-translate, google-translation-api, googletrans

I am trying to translate a text using googletrans.

It was working  fine till yesterday.

Today it gave an error:

> Googletrans raising an error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I have tried the code on different systems, but it is not working.
Here is my code.

I am using googletrans for translating for last week. It never gave such type of error. Today only it gave an error.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator=Translator()
translator.translate(text='hello', dest='de').text

Output:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: chekout the solution proposed in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497391/googletrans-api-error-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0

Comment: Hi Raghav!
Is the proposed solution working for you?

Answer (score 2):

i have encountered it before, It is actually because the limitation of the translation by using API... We need to wait for 1 day to reset the IP and you can try another day to run it, it might be work