# Google Cloud Translate vs Python googletrans

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api, googletrans, google-cloud-translate

I have been thinking about developing a new product which has to be capable of translating text to several different languages. While I was doing my research, I have found the Python library named "[googletrans](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)", which is completely free to use. However, I also found something named [Google Cloud Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate) which has a price to use.

I have made some tests with googletrans library. It seemed OK to me, for my project at least. I wanted to ask that is it really the case? I mean, do these 2 APIs have any difference? Also, is it alright to develop a device that works googletrans on it, without any payment?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, "googletrans" as a **daily limit** and if you exceeds it your requests may be blocked, so you have to wait the next day to use it ([Googletrans API error - daily limit or blocked IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672411/googletrans-api-error-daily-limit-or-blocked-ip)). It has even the **maximum character limit on a single text is 15k** (https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/). According to the terms of service, I'm not sure if you can use it for commercial purposes.

Anyway, I think it's a great free alternative and if you use it for personal projects it should be perfect.