# Translate a big amount of data, pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-translate, google-translation-api

I would like to translate the text of a column of my dataframe, the goal is to harmonize the data. I have text in Chinese, English, French, German, Spanish etc... I want to have all the text in English. 
I have tried several things: with the googletrans API
1)naively try to do it

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df["translated"] = df.apply(lambda row :translator.translate(row['name']).text,axis = 1)
Out:JSONDecodeError: ('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)', 'occurred at index 1816997')
```

2) by resetting the API each time
[GoogleTrans API Error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497391/googletrans-api-error-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0)
Using this link I ran this code: and I still have an error..

```
import copy
from googletrans import Translator

translatedList = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # REINITIALIZE THE API
    translator = Translator()
    newrow = copy.deepcopy(row)
    try:
        # translate the 'text' column
        translated = translator.translate(row['name'], dest='en')
        newrow['translated'] = translated.text
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        continue
    translatedList.append(newrow)

Out: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

3) I also tried to bypass the limit of the google API by changing IPs.

test with vpn: does not work

```
 import random

listofservers = ["South Africa", "Egypt" , "Australia", "New Zealand",  "South Korea", "Singapore", "Taiwan", "Vietnam", "Hong Kong", "Indonesia", "Thailand", "Japan", "Malaysia", "United Kingdom", "Netherlands", "Germany", "France", "Belgium", "Switzerland", "Sweden","Spain","Denmark", "Italy", "Norway", "Austria", "Romania", "Czech Republic", "Luxembourg", "Poland", "Finland", "Hungary", "Latvia", "Russia", "Iceland", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Moldova", "Portugal", "Albania", "Ireland", "Slovakia","Ukraine", "Cyprus", "Estonia", "Georgia", "Greece", "Serbia", "Slovenia", "Azerbaijan", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Macedonia","India", 'Turkey', 'Israel', 'United Arab Emirates', 'United States', 'Canada','Mexico'
,"Brazil", "Costa Rica", "Argentina", "Chile"]

def SelectServer(l):
    return random.choice(l)

def translate_text(text, dest_language="en"):  
    # Used to translate using the googletrans library
    translator = googletrans.Translator()
    try:

        translation = translator.translate(text=text, dest=dest_language)

    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        # api call restriction

        print("exception !! déconection du VPN ")
        process = subprocess.Popen(["nordvpn", "-d"], shell = True ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        process.wait()

        time.sleep(5)

        srv = SelectServer(listofservers)

        print("sélection du serveur  : "+ srv + " et connexion")

        process = subprocess.Popen(["nordvpn", "-c", "-g", srv ], shell = True ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        process.wait()
        time.sleep(60)

        return translate_text(text=text, dest_language=dest_language)

    return translation.text

Out : ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027016006488>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]
```

I greatly appreciate your help,
Chris.

Comment: What is your question? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to translate 2 million of data  (strings) from any language into English. @AMC

Answer (score 1):

I was working XML file for translate and I was getting this error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". When I searched this error, I encountered that some special characters fails translation. In this case `&nbsp; &amp; etc.` were problem for me. If there are special characters in your text, copy-paste to google translate web-site and see is there a error.

Another reason for this errors can be about too much request or character limit. If you are using list instead of string, Each index in your list means a new request for translation. If there are too much request, google bans your IP for a time.

I collect my texts in a string variable. I add [text number] to begining of each text and seperates them with /n then sending to tranlation. Like;

```
[1]First Text\n
[2]SecondText\n
[3]Third Text\n
```

Google Translate can translate 10000 characters in single request so character limit is 10000 for a string variable. Also I add a timer for 100 seconds between each requests to escape from ban. Its working for me.

PS: I tried proxy for bypass the ban but it didn't worked for me. I connected my phone internet via hotspot and it worked.