# Does there exist a way to translate one word into all possible translations in another language in bulk in python?

Tags: python, language-translation

I have a list of words, and a few definitions as follows:
word - trans1, trans2, trans3 ...
I'm now unsure if all those translations are correct. I want to use a library that for that given word gives all translations possible
word - trans1 ... transn
I'll then match each of my translations to those provided by the library / translation software, and make sure that it is a valid translation. The problem is I don't know of such a library. I do not want something like googletrans as it only provides one possible translation [because it is used to translating paragraphs] and there is a clear word / search limit every time I use it, stopping abruptly after a few with just running a few trials. It also is inconsistent in its translation pattern, for example sometimes adding "to" to the infinitives of verbs and sometimes not. Is there something like this that exists? Essentially what I want is a many result English-destinationlanguage dictionary library.

Answer (score 1):

Google Translate API is probably your best bet out there. I'm no Google fanboy but credit where credit's due, and Google Translate is probably the best in the game right now.

As far as the problem of the program abruptly stopping, make sure that you're using the API correctly([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60266135/8661686)).

As far as the infinitives are concerned, machines generally suck at translation, to understand [watch this great video by Tom Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAgp7nXdkLU&feature=youtu.be).