# How to use HolaVPN to resolve googletrans's JSON Decode error: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, nlp, google-translate, language-translation

I have a vietnamese dataset of 18k rows that I'm trying to translate to English using googletrans module.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

def  trans_text(df, text_field):
    df[text_field] = df[text_field].apply(translator.translate, src='vi', dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))  
    return df
trans_text(df_train.sample(1), "question")
```

I end up with the following JSONDecode error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d6791d78575e> in <module>()
     24     df[text_field] = df[text_field].apply(translator.translate, src='vi', dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
     25     return df
---> 26 trans_text(df_train.sample(1), "question")
     27 
     28 

<ipython-input-21-d6791d78575e> in trans_text(df, text_field)
     22 
     23 def  trans_text(df, text_field):
---> 24     df[text_field] = df[text_field].apply(translator.translate, src='vi', dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
     25     return df
     26 trans_text(df_train.sample(1), "question")

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in f(x)
   4183 
   4184             def f(x):
-> 4185                 return func(x, *args, **kwds)
   4186 
   4187         else:

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    170 
    171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
    173 
    174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src)
     79         r = self.session.get(url, params=params)
     80 
---> 81         data = utils.format_json(r.text)
     82         return data
     83 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py in format_json(original)
     60         converted = json.loads(original)
     61     except ValueError:
---> 62         converted = legacy_format_json(original)
     63 
     64     return converted

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py in legacy_format_json(original)
     52             text = text[:p] + states[j][1] + text[nxt:]
     53 
---> 54     converted = json.loads(text)
     55     return converted
     56 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/opt/anaconda3/envs/sam-pycaret/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I understand this arising due to a ban on my IP. I looked up ways to circumvent this and found that using VPN is worth the shot. I have HolaVPN installed already. However, being a newbie to all this, I'm not sure of how I could reproduce same steps as in the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57025015/14332337) for hola instead. Any tips on a clear procedure to follow could greatly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library makes a request and without checking the status code assumes that the requests was successful:

```
     79         r = self.session.get(url, params=params)
     80 
---> 81         data = utils.format_json(r.text)
```

Now, Google might not like your request for any reason it and return an error message with a matching status code (4xx, 5xx). The library still tries to parse the body as JSON which does not work since there is no body and raises a `JSONDecodeError` that is unrelated to the original problem. You can't see the real cause.

Conclusion: the `googletrans` library is missing crucial error handling. You may have to edit it and add error handling yourself.