# Python Google Translate API error : How to translate a large amount of data

Tags: python, dataset, translation, google-translate, data-augmentation

## My problem

I would like to use a kind of data-augmentation method for NLP consisting of back-translating dataset.

Basically, I have a large dataset ([SNLI](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/snli/)), consisting of 1 100 000 english sentences. What I need to do is : translate these sentences in a language, and translate it back to English.

I may have to do this for several language. So I have **a lot** of translations to do.

*I need a free solution.*

---

## What I did so far

I tried several python module for translation, but due to recent changes in Google Translate API, most of them do not work. [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) seems to work if we apply this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456197/9494790).

However, it is not working for big dataset. There is a limit of 15K characters by Google (as pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497391/googletrans-api-error-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021371/jsondecodeerror-using-google-translate-api-with-python3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957624/python-google-translate-api-error)). The first link show a supposed work-around.

---

## Where I am blocked

Even if I apply the [work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497469/9494790) (initializing the Translator every iteration), it is not working, and I got the following error :

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried using proxies and others Google translate URLs :

```
URLS = ['translate.google.com', 'translate.google.co.kr', 'translate.google.ac', 'translate.google.ad', 'translate.google.ae', ...]

proxies = {    'http': '1.243.64.63:48730',   'https': '59.11.98.253:42645', }

t = Translator(service_urls=URLS, proxies=proxies)
```

But it's not changing anything.

---

## Note

My problem might come from the fact that I am using multi-threading : 100 workers for translating the whole dataset. If they work in parallel, maybe they use more than 15k characters together.

But I should use multi-threading. If I don't, it will take several weeks to translate the whole dataset...

---

## My question

**How do I fix this error so I can translate all sentences ?**

If it's not possible, **is there any free alternative, to get machine translation in Python (not mandatory to use Google Translate), for such a big dataset ?**

Comment: Did you find any solution ?? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @AqibHameed Nope I couldn't find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One million characters is pretty much text to be translated.

Currently, the Google Cloud Translation V3 offers a [free tier quota](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing#prices_per_month) that you may want to use (1-500,000 characters free per month). Since it doesn't seem to be enough for your use case, you probably need to create more than one billing accounts or wait for a month to translate more text.

Check [this link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text-v3#translate_translate_text_beta-python) to know how you can perform a text translation with python.