# Get list of words in different languages using python

Tags: python, nltk, pyenchant

I'm trying to get a list of all words in a language in the same way `NLTK` is providing for english. See example for english:

I already tried to use `pyenchant` to achieve a similar result but the documentation not being updated I have some troubles downloading an italian dictionary (MacOS).

```
from nltk.corpus import words
print(words.words())
```

Is it possible to get a similar list in french, german and italian?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine googletrans and nltk as the following:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
from googletrans import Translator

french = []
translator = Translator()

for in_english in words.words():
    in_french = translator.translate(in_english, dest='fr')
    french.append(in_french.text)
    print in_french.text

print french
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal! Nevertheless, the module being unofficial and unstable I already get problems linked to [jsondecodeerror-using-google-translate-api-with-python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021371/jsondecodeerror-using-google-translate-api-with-python3).

Comment: No problem. You let us know if you find something better !